# Xcode 6.1 freezing every 5 seconds

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6.1

Suddenly my Xcode 6.1 started freezing every 5 seconds as I am trying to code. I have tried the following:

1. Restarting Xcode
2. Killing the process
3. Restarting computer
4. Turning off source control in preferences
5. Deleting derived data / snap shots / archives
6. Cleaning build

Nothing helped

> 11/6/14 12:12:45.000 PM kernel[0]: process Xcode[28291] thread 246720 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU (Actual recent usage: 85%) over 180 seconds. thread lifetime cpu usage 243.955727 seconds, (233.793051 user, 10.162676 system) ledger info: balance: 90002680643 credit: 238154008329 debit: 148151327686 limit: 90000000000 (50%) period: 180000000000 time since last refill (ns): 105560692320

- Xcode 6.1
- OS X 10.9.4
- MacBook Pro Retina

A CPU usage report: http://pastebin.com/UhNCbWf6

Comment: Same problem, probably a bug. Try downloading it again, worked for me

Comment: You could also try to remove any plugins that you might have installed and keep an eye on the downloads (xcode prefs). Xcode 6 has a lot of bugs that's for sure...

Comment: No plugins installed, and only downloads are ios simulators =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reverting all my xib changes and it fixed it. One of the xibs became corrupted for some reason and xcode was stuck trying to compile it over and over.